# Open office spreadsheet, export as PDF as single large page?

Tags: pdf, openoffice

I have an open office spreadsheet. I need to export a selection as a PDF. Everything I do this it creates a PDF document with multiple pages and moves some columns to the next page as they dont fit. How can I just export everything into a single page as a PDF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940236/how-to-generate-pdf-from-a-libreoffice-calc-sheet-fitting-the-page-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to 'File' > 'Page Preview'

Then 'Format page' button on the toolbar

Then click 'Sheet' tab. At the bottom select scaling mode 'Fit print to number of pages' 
Then choose 1 page next to it. Click OK.

Then press the Export PDF button on the toolbar up top to get your spreadsheet as one page in a PDF.

Comment: Can't find File > Page preview on 5.0.2.2

Comment: Depending on the version the path can also be, 'Format' > 'Page' > 'Sheet' > 'Scale'.